# Querying Amazon

Tags: iphone

Is is possible to querying Amazon for items. Regarding their prices, discounts, category etc?
If yes then how can we access it and get results on iphone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you're looking for [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/), specifically the Amazon Associates Web Service (A2S)? According to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Associates_Web_Service) article you can use it to browse their catalog and retrieve product information etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Product Advertising API

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/

Use the ItemLookup operation to find the item in question.  Depending on what ResponseGroup you choose, you can get just about every piece of information about a product.